# How to make a https request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I need to make a crawler. For http request i used to do this.

```
 var http=require('http');
 var options={
   host:'http://www.example.com',
   path:'/foo/example'
 };

 callback=function(response){
 var str='';
 response.on('data',function(chunk){
 str+=chunk;
 });
 response.on('end', function () {
       console.log(str);
 });
 }
 http.request(options, callback).end();
```

but I have to make a crawler for  https://example.com/foo/example
If I am using the same for https://example.com/foo/example it is giving this error

```
 events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Comment: Did you check [`https` module's `request` method](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend this excellent HTTP Request module: http://unirest.io/nodejs.html

You can install it with:

> npm install -g unirest

Here's some example Node code with Unirest:

```
  var url = 'https://somewhere.com/';
  unirest.get(url)
    .end(function(response) {
      var body = response.body;
      // TODO: parse the body
      done();
    });
```

...so to get the HTML at www.purple.com you'd do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

function getHTML(url, next) {
  var unirest = require('unirest');
  unirest.get(url)
    .end(function(response) {
      var body = response.body;
      if (next) next(body);
    });
}

getHTML('http://purple.com/', function(html) {
  console.log(html);
});
```

Comment: The data (elements and their attributes) which i am getting is not the same as it is visible in the inspect element. It is totally different or you can say encoded.

Comment: unirest.get(url) will get the text data at a URL. When you inspect the page, you're looking at the page after JavaScript has run over it - so you're not seeing the raw HTML - you're seeing the DOM after JavaScript mods.

Comment: so can you the tell the way to see the raw html. Thanks